# mkii, mkiv tags for ConTeXt related questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

While looking at the (IMO very good) question [Storing and retrieving data in tuc file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-tuc-file), I think that the [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex) tag is inappropriate, it should be `mkiv` or `contextmarkiv` or something similar. This is because this question does not apply on the (here default) LaTeX format with LuaTeX. A specific `mkiv` tag would be much better for future searches.

Comment: Does [tag:context] alone not cover this, when combined with [tag:luatex]?

Comment: @JosephWright from a "person asking a question" point of view it would suffice, but I am thinking of searching. When I am looking for LuaTeX specific things *I* am not interested in ConTeXt only questions/answers, they don't help me. This is somewhat related to the fact that the "default" tag here is "LaTeX". I would not consider the mentioned question really related to LuaTeX (in the strict sense, of course, but any answer would not apply to LuaTeX).

Comment: Understood. Does searching for `[luatex] -[context]` or `[luatex] [context]` (depending on the case) cover this? (I'm not against the idea, I'm just making sure I understand the concept properly.)

Comment: @JosephWright Correct. `[luatex] -[context]` would almost do the same job, but not quite: `[luatex]` and `[context]` in a question could mean that the OP is happy with either a LuaTeX or a ConTeXt question (but unlikely), but `[mkiv]` would make things clearer.

Comment: I think that the trouble is that `[luatex]` is a synonym for `[lualatex]` (and `[pdftex]` is a synonym for `[pdflatex]`. 

Shouldn't `[luatex]` refer to the engine and `[lualatex]` and `[mkiv]` refer to the macro formats. Similarly, `[pdftex]` should refer to the engine and `[pdflatex]` and `[mkii]` to the macro format.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind about tags is that they need to be fairly obvious and explanatory to the people asking the questions. So adding a `[markiv]` tag or equivalent, even if it it useful for searching, is unlikely to be added by users.

Comment: @Aditya As I understood it, that was the point of the [tag:pdftex], [tag:luatex] and [tag:xetex] tags. I'd only apply them to questions which are in some way related to the engine in use.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't think that's true: the [tag:lualatex] tag is a synonym for [tag:luatex], I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn I thought that was because we don't have a [tag:latex] tag. So if you try to tag as [tag:lualatex], what you are saying is your question is in some way LuaTeX-specific, but using the LaTeX format. So we strip out the LaTeX part, and leave the fact that it's engine-specific.

Comment: @AlanMunn mkiv or MarkIV is a common name for the current ConTeXt format. See for example: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Running_Mark_IV

Comment: @PatrickGundlach Do you have a sense of how many current questions would benefit from a `[mkiv]` tag?

Comment: @AlanMunn 10% of the 136 ConTeXt questions have either `[context]` and `[lua]` or `[context]` and `[luatex]`, so the current situation leads to confusion whether the OP should use `[luatex]` or `[lua]` together with `[context]` - a `[mkiv]` tag would have helped with these questions. A `[mkii]` tag could express that the OP is  interested in a pdfTeX/XeTeX ConTeXt solution, a `[mkiv]` tag shows that a LuaTeX based ConTeXt solution would be fine, both tags could represent a "choice does not matter" question.

Comment: Well it's worth a try, I guess. Whether or not people actually use it is another thing.  I would strongly recommend creating `mk{ii|iv}` suffixes for the `[context]` tag: i.e. `[context-mkii]` and `[context-mkiv]` along with very clear tag wikis to distinguish them rather than simple `[mkii]` and `[mkiv]` tags, which will not show up in the tag list when people try to add a `[context]` tag.

Comment: @AlanMunn Make that an answer?

Comment: Since we now have them: Do we agree that a mk(ii|iv) question should be tagged with [context] _and_ [context-mk(ii|iv)]? That's how they do it over at `dba` with the [oracle tag](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle/info).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I'm a bit skeptical that the tags will get used, it's worth a try.  I propose  creating `mk{ii|iv}` suffixes for the [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag: i.e. [context-mkii](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-mkii) and [context-mkiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-mkiv) along with very clear tag wikis to distinguish them rather than simple `[mkii]` and `[mkiv]` tags, which will not show up in the tag list when people try to add a [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw that Patrick Gundlach has added the new [context-mkiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-mkiv) tag to the first two questions, while at the same time removing [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex)  and [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context). I'm not familiar with any of these tag subjects, and it may well be that questions about [context-mkiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-mkiv) may be of no interest to the "general luaTeX" user, but I suggest that questions about MkIV should also feature the general [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag. For now, I re-added this tag to the two questions.

Comment: "..but I suggest that questions about MkIV should also feature the general context tag" - would you mind to elaborate why you suggest to add the tag?

Comment: @Patrick Because many MkIV questions may also be of interest for general ConTeXt users.

Comment: You're right. I'll keep the {context} tag in the next retag session :)